# Word to describe "compliance with unspoken resistance"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, vocabulary

What I'm looking for is a word to describe "compliance with unspoken resistance" or something of the like.  In other words, one complies, unwillingly.  However, the unwillingness, is not stated outright, it is partially implied.

Any suggestions?

I was thinking "submission", but I'm not sure if it carries the full weight of what I would like to say..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per Vocabulary.com, *resignation* is:

([the quality or state of being resigned : submissiveness](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/resignation) / [an unresisting acceptance of a change or fate you don't necessarily like](http://vocabulary-vocabulary.com/dictionary/resignation.php) / [state of uncomplaining, utter frustration](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Resignation))

---

Examples:

- [You can just keep on trying to survive, day to day, in an unsatisfying marriage—I call this adjusting with *resignation*.](http://books.google.com/books?id=_wT_c9Hk1_kC&pg=PA5&dq=%22with+resignation%22&hl=en&ei=qCHiTKGhCZGKhQesr62qDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=9&ved=0CEwQ6AEwCA) Jeffry H. Larson, *The Great Marriage Tune-Up Book: A Proven Program for Evaluating* (2002)
- [A Christian knocked the cap into the mud, crying, " 'Jew! Get off the pavement!'" "'And what did you do?'" asked the young Freud. The father told how he complied with *resignation*, stepping off the sidewalk to retrieve his cap.](http://books.google.com/books?id=7eq8sztgTs8C&pg=PA43&dq=complied+with+resignation&hl=en&ei=NC7iTK6eKMWwhAf1ptm1DQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBQ) François Ansermet, *Biology of freedom: neural plasticity, experience, and the unconscious* (2007)
- [... and the benefits of their example (who have persisted in doing their duty with *resignation* to the Divine Will, amids.](http://books.google.com/books?id=FCMGAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA87&dq=%22with+resignation%22&hl=en&ei=DSPiTOyPJ4rPhAfnjNnGDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAjgU) Samuel Richardson, *Pamela; or, Virtue rewarded* (1816)

Comment: Thanks for the word, but more importantly, the examples!  That's awesome! :)

Answer (score 5):

**Acquiescence**

[(Passive assent or agreement without protest.)](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/acquiescence)

It should be noted that the word does necessarily cover the intended meaning of unwillingness. Some definitions actually indicate [quiet satisfaction](http://www.onelook.com/?other=web1913&w=Acquiescence).

---

Examples:

- [… the tender understanding with which he had *acquiesced* to her wish not to consummate their relationship out of wedlock.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acquiescing) Dorothy West, *The Wedding* (1995)
- [Some rape statutes, for example, use consent in both factual and legal senses, referring sometimes to *acquiescence* that may or not be a defense depending upon whether it is voluntary…](http://books.google.com/books?id=17bAKRvHBkcC&pg=PA339&dq=Acquiescence&hl=en&ei=Bx7iTPvvK8SIhQeW-_nODQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBTgU#v=onepage&q=Acquiescence&f=false) Peter Westen, *The logic of consent: the diversity and deceptiveness of consent* (2004)

Comment: I like both words, but I believe resignation is a little more appropriate in the context I plan to use it in, but, I'm looking forward to adding Acquiescence to my vocabulary!

Comment: Another example: ["You can tell him I'm disinclined to acquiesce to that request"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfFM9JlQx10&t=0m23s)